# how to get location values of original vector after sorting

Tags: r

i am sorting a vector. my matrix is too large, so. here's a simple example below instead.

```
x <- c(10,3,5)
x1 <- sort(x, decreasing=T)

print(x1)
10 5 3 
loc_vals <- ??? 
print(loc_vals)
1 3 2
```

wondering how to get the location values of raw data after sorting as shown in the output of  print(loc_vals)

many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at

```
?order
```

It will give you the order of the vector's entry after the sorting.  Try

```
loc_vals <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
x[loc_vals]
```

Comment: `order(x)` is required no? `order(x1)` is trivial and uninteresting if it has been sorted.

Comment: Ah, ignore me. @Ritchie Cotton has edited to clarify what you meant